# Abaqus - stress-displacement elements are not allowed in a heat transfer analysis

Tags: physics, simulation

I'm trying to simulate cooling of cylinder-shaped sample, but when I submit a job I get an error: stress-displacement elements are not allowed in a heat transfer analysis. I defined part, material(density, specific heat, conductivity), section, section assignments, mesh, instance, predefined field (temperature) in initial step, step-1 (heat transfer) with interaction (surface film condition). Where's the problem ?

**Update:**
I solved that problem: I had an incorrect element type. For the heat transfer simulation: Mesh -> Element Type -> Family -> Heat Transfer. I guess that also Convection/Diffusion option in the Hex tab should be selected.

Comment: We don't have a chance in hell of solving this without knowing more about the software. The physics looks correct, so either the code is buggy or one of those elements actually has stress-displacement behavior. Do you have a heat-transfer case that works? Can you talk to the authors of the code?

Comment: I'm using Abaqus CAE Student Edition 6.11-2.